# HTML table is not acting as supposed

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create basic chat using ASPX and HTML. The output itself is fine but the problem is that the table just keeps growing and growing. I want it to be scrollable instead. Here's
what I tried and its not working:

```
<td style="height: 100px">
    <div style="overflow:scroll;display:block">
        <%=output %>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the div's height in order to the browser know when to start clipping the content.

```
<div style="overflow:scroll;display:block;height:200px">
```

Comment: BTW what is the diffrence when using style parameters in div or in td?

Comment: In order to clip the content and provide the scrolling, the browser needs to know the element's height, in this case you want the scroll the div content, not the TD's. You could use the TD too, just need to set "height" and "overflow" on the same element.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `overflow: scroll;` to your table css.

```
<table style="display:block; overflow: scroll; height:100px">
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/orlando/uUpvd/

Comment: i tried it but when the chat is "full" and some one adding a message the table just strech